# ShapedRecipe with Lore?

Tags: java, minecraft, bukkit

I'm writing a CraftBukkit Plugin for my server. But I couldn't find how to check if an ingredient item has lore

```
ShapedRecipe packedice = new ShapedRecipe(new ItemStack(Material.PACKED_ICE));
packedice.shape(new String[]{"aba","bcb","aba"}).setIngredient('a', Material.PRISMARINE_SHARD).setIngredient('b', Material.GOLD_BLOCK).setIngredient('c', Material.SNOW_BALL);
Bukkit.getServer().addRecipe(packedice);
```

Answer (score 1):

instead of `ShapedRecipe packedice = new ShapedRecipe(new ItemStack(Material.PACKED_ICE));`
you need a bit more code:

```
ItemStack i = new ItemStack(Material.PACKED_ICE);
ItemMeta m = i.getItemMeta();
m.setDisplayName("CustomDisplayName")
List<String> l = new ArrayList<String>();
l.add("Line 1");
l.add("Line 2");
m.setLore(l);
i.setItemMeta(m);
ShapedRecipe packedice = new ShapedRecipe(i);
```

Hope it helps

//EDIT:
Sorry i missunderstod you first, This will check if the Item in the upper right corner has the Lore `"Line1"`:

```
@EventHandler
public void onCraft(CraftItemEvent e) {
    ShapedRecipe packedice = YOURRECIPE;
    if(e.getInventory().getSize() == 10 && e.getInventory().getResult().equals(packedice.getResult())) {
        if(e.getRawSlot() == 0) {
            ItemStack upleft = e.getInventory().getItem(1);
            if(upleft != null && upleft.hasItemMeta() && upleft.getItemMeta().hasLore()) {
                List<String> l = upleft.getItemMeta().getLore();
                if(!l.get(0).equals("Line 1")) {
                    e.setCancelled(true);
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: does this codes check  if item hasn't lore, doesn't craft?

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately the Bukkit API does not provide a way to register recipe ingredientes with a custom `ItemMeta` (the item part that stores lore and NBT data), but you can circumvent that limitation in two ways:

**1)** Register the recipe without the custom meta and check if it exists when you a player attempts to create them, the item will be shown in the output slot but the player will not be able to get it.
Video showing this example in progress: https://youtu.be/zbSf_wATaGk

```
public void onEnable()
{
    final ShapedRecipe packedice = new ShapedRecipe(new ItemStack(Material.PACKED_ICE));
    packedice.shape(new String[]{"aba","bcb","aba"}).setIngredient('a', Material.PRISMARINE_SHARD).setIngredient('b', Material.GOLD_BLOCK).setIngredient('c', Material.SNOW_BALL);
    Bukkit.addRecipe(packedice);
    Bukkit.getPluginManager().registerEvents(new Listener()
    {

        @EventHandler
        void onCraft(CraftItemEvent event)
        {
            // Check if it's being crafted with your custom recipe
            // You can check only the event.getRecipe().getResult() if you are not worried about recipe conflicts.
            if(!matches(packedice, event.getInventory().getMatrix()))
                return;

            // The lore that will be required in all prismarine shards
            List<String> neededLore = Arrays.asList("Line1","Line2");

            // Check if all prismarine shares has that lore,
            // you can check only one of them or whatever item you want
            // The indexes are:
            // 0 1 2 | Shard Gold Shard
            // 3 4 5 | Gold  Snow Gold
            // 4 7 8 | Shard Gold Shard
            ItemStack[] matrix = event.getInventory().getMatrix();
            for(ItemStack item: matrix)
                if(item != null && item.getType() == Material.PRISMARINE_SHARD)
                    if(!neededLore.equals(item.getItemMeta().getLore()))
                    {
                        event.setCancelled(true);
                        return;
                    }
        }
    }, this);
}

/**
 * Checks if a crafting matrix matches a recipe
 */
public static boolean matches(ShapedRecipe recipe, ItemStack[] matrix)
{
    String[] shapeStr = recipe.getShape();
    int len = 0;
    for(String line : shapeStr)
        len += line.length();

    char[] shape = new char[len];
    int shapeIndex = 0;
    for(String line : shapeStr)
        for(char c: line.toCharArray())
            shape[shapeIndex++] = c;

    for(int i = 0; i < shape.length; i++)
    {
        ItemStack required = recipe.getIngredientMap().get(shape[i]);
        ItemStack found = matrix[i];
        if(found == null || !required.getData().equals(found.getData()))
            return false;
    }

    return true;
}
```

**2)** You can go beyond Bukkit API and use CraftBukkit and Minecraft objects to register a custom recipe object that checks the NBT tags, that way the player will not see any output unless he uses the exact same item as registered in recipe, you can also register recipe for renamed or enchanted objects.
Video show this example in progress: https://youtu.be/Gr3ADckGBUA

```
public void onEnable()
{
    ItemStack shard = new ItemStack(Material.PRISMARINE_SHARD);
    ItemMeta itemMeta = shard.getItemMeta();
    itemMeta.setLore(Arrays.asList("Line1", "Line2"));
    shard.setItemMeta(itemMeta);

    registerShapedRecipe(new ItemStack(Material.PACKED_ICE),
            "aba", "bcb", "aba",
            'a', shard,
            'b', new ItemStack(Material.GOLD_BLOCK),
            'c', new ItemStack(Material.SNOW_BALL)
    );
}

/**
 * Register a recipe that checks for NBT Tags.
 *
 * Require these imports:
 * import net.minecraft.server.v1_8_R3.*;
 * import org.bukkit.craftbukkit.v1_8_R3.inventory.CraftItemStack;
 *
 * Change v1_8_R3 to match your craftbukkit version
 */
public static void registerShapedRecipe(ItemStack result, Object... data)
{
    String s = "";
    int index = 0;
    int height = 0;
    int width = 0;
    if(data[index] instanceof String[])
    {
        String[] strings = (String[])data[index++];

        for(String shapedRecipes : strings)
        {
            ++width;
            height = shapedRecipes.length();
            s = s + shapedRecipes;
        }
    }
    else
    {
        while(data[index] instanceof String) {
            String str = (String)data[index++];
            ++width;
            height = str.length();
            s = s + str;
        }
    }

    HashMap<Character, net.minecraft.server.v1_8_R3.ItemStack> charMap;
    for(charMap = Maps.newHashMap(); index < data.length; index += 2)
    {
        Character c = (Character)data[index];
        net.minecraft.server.v1_8_R3.ItemStack stack = null;
        if(data[index + 1] instanceof ItemStack)
            stack = CraftItemStack.asNMSCopy((ItemStack) data[index + 1]);
        else if(data[index + 1] instanceof Item)
            stack = new net.minecraft.server.v1_8_R3.ItemStack((Item)data[index + 1]);
        else if(data[index + 1] instanceof net.minecraft.server.v1_8_R3.Block)
            stack = new net.minecraft.server.v1_8_R3.ItemStack((net.minecraft.server.v1_8_R3.Block)data[index + 1], 1, Short.MAX_VALUE);
        else if(data[index + 1] instanceof net.minecraft.server.v1_8_R3.ItemStack)
            stack = (net.minecraft.server.v1_8_R3.ItemStack)data[index + 1];


        charMap.put(c, stack);
    }

    net.minecraft.server.v1_8_R3.ItemStack[] ingredients = new net.minecraft.server.v1_8_R3.ItemStack[height * width];

    for(int j = 0; j < height * width; ++j)
    {
        char c = s.charAt(j);
        if(charMap.containsKey(c))
            ingredients[j] = charMap.get(c).cloneItemStack();
        else
            ingredients[j] = null;
    }

    ShapedRecipes recipe = new ShapedRecipes(height, width, ingredients, CraftItemStack.asNMSCopy(result))
    {
        /**
         * The method name can change depending on your CraftBukkit version!
         */
        @Override
        public boolean a(InventoryCrafting inventory, World world)
        {
            for(int i = 0; i < ingredients.length; i++)
            {
                net.minecraft.server.v1_8_R3.ItemStack ingredient = ingredients[i];
                net.minecraft.server.v1_8_R3.ItemStack found = inventory.getItem(i);
                if(ingredient == null)
                {
                    if(found == null)
                        continue;
                    else
                        return false;
                }

                if(found == null)
                    return false;

                if(ingredient.getItem() != found.getItem() || ingredient.getData() != found.getData())
                    return false;

                if(ingredient.hasTag())
                {
                    if(!found.hasTag())
                        return false;

                    if(!ingredient.getTag().equals(found.getTag()))
                        return false;
                }
            }

            return true;
        }
    };

    CraftingManager.getInstance().recipes.add(recipe);
}
```